# HERE maps Python SDK v2 failing to authenticate with the platform

Tags: here-api, heremaps, here-maps-rest

I am struggling with accessing resources on the HERE platform using the Python Data SDK v2. Specifically I am trying to run the following example notebook:

https://github.com/heremaps/here-data-sdk-examples-python/blob/main/tutorials/ProcessSDIIData_platform.ipynb

It seems like I don't have access to that resource (I get a "forbidden" message when trying to open the resource in the browser). Therefore I changed the used HRN to one of the resources/catalogs that were accessible in the Data Manager. Unfortunately I am still getting the same error message:

```
AuthenticationException: An error occurred during authentication or authorization with HERE
                    platform: Status 403 -
                    Reason Forbidden
 Response: {"error":"Forbidden","error_description":"These credentials do not authorize access"}
```

If anyone has an idea about how to deal with this that would help me a great deal.

Answer (score 0):

These catalogs are not publicly available, hence you are getting forbidden message. You need to reach out to us via [contact us](https://developer.here.com/?form_id=2227&form_category=contact-us&cta_id=521_contact-us&detailed_source=cms.developer.here.com%2F) form and provide the exact use case to get the access for the same. Thanks

~MS